# ReactJS: How to clear an image preview from a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A component of a library I'm using is essentially a wrapper around `<input type=file>`, which manages the buttons to upload a new image, change it or remove it, while also providing a thumbnail of it. This is its simplified definition:

```
import defaultImage from "assets/images/default_image.jpg";

export default function ImageUpload(props) {
  const { image, setImage } = props;
  const [imagePreviewUrl, setImagePreviewUrl] = useState(defaultImage);
  let fileInput = React.createRef();
  const handleImageChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const imageFile = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const image = reader.result;
      setImage(image);
      setImagePreviewUrl(image);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };
  const handleRemove = () => {
    setImage("");
    setImagePreviewUrl(defaultImage);
    fileInput.current.value = null;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={handleImageChange}
        ref={fileInput}
      />
      <div>
        <img src={imagePreviewUrl} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {image === null ? (
          <Button onClick={() => handleClick()}> {"Select image"} </Button>
        ) : (
          <span>
            <Button {...changeButtonProps} onClick={() => handleClick()}> Change </Button>
            <Button {...removeButtonProps} onClick={() => handleRemove()}> Remove </Button>
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The parent is basically collecting this and other components's states and stores them into a redux store. All works well, until I try to clear the preview image.

As `input` is not a controlled component in react, I'm not quite sure how to do that.
I though about passing the `setImagePreviewUrl` as a prop, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it.

How can I clear that preview image?

Comment: You're already resetting it to the default image, so what's the issue?

Comment: Yeah it works fine. Check this sandbox where App is the parent that handles image and setImage https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-knuth-zoqdy

Comment: Your sandbox appears to function correctly. I only see some need for handling clicking "change" and then cancelling, but other than that, when I click "remove" the default stairwell image returns. What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you try hiding the preview image than add condition like this:

```
<div>
   {imagePreviewUrl && <img src={imagePreviewUrl} /> }
</div>
```

See full example by your code in the playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s524255

Comment: That was it! Silly me that I wanted to supply another function just to clear that field. Works like a charm, thanks!